# How to Sort View control by Lookup column

Tags: xpages

I have two forms that are related and I would to combine them in a view control. Not that difficult. This is for a "1 to Many" type scenario.

Say I have a customer view with the columns customerID and Customer Name.  Then I have a view showing the "many" documents that has the columns masterCustomerID, orderNumber, orderDate.

On the XPage I create a view control of the many documents and add the columns masterCustomerID, orderNumber, orderDate.  Then I add a column in the front to do a DbLookup to pull in the actual name of the customer.  Nothing too fancy really.

My question is, in this situation, where the lookup column is the FIRST column.  What are the strategies to sort the view column by that column.  By default it would sort by the Key Value in the order view which is likely different then the Name values.

I'm not averse to using repeat controls if that would be easier.

My first thought would be to employ TreeMaps somehow, but I don't know if that's practical in the event that there might be a LOT of documents.  Maybe there's something I'm missing...

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you want them sorted by name, your view must be sorted by name at first place. Then lookup rest of the values (orders).

Comment: I think that the problem is that the view is sorted by customerID and that he wants to sort it by customerName, but the customer name isn't available in the order documents (only the customerID). I can think of 2 ways to solve this issue: (1) process all documents from the large view, resolve the customerID, store that in a TreeMap and bind the result to a datatable/ repeat (could give you perf problems) (2) store the customer name in the order document. BTW: you should implement a caching mechanism to store customer names after you've looked them up: will give you much better performance.

Comment: Seriously: store the customer name redundant in the many documents (it is Notes after all ;-) ). Then have some code in the querysave of the person document that checks if the name was altered and kick off an update agent. The pseudo relational approach will kill your performance

Answer (score 0):

Use view with (Customer name, Customer ID) structure as main view. Then based on Customer ID populate other columns by lookup from view with structure (Customer ID, Order ID, Order date). Hence it is 1:N relationship, you can't use single view component, but two nested - repeat inside view column would do.

I hope you are aware of performance impact (orders looked up for every customer row), so don't try to show too many customers at once.